# getting error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in spyder although file is available at location

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file in spyder and print its content with below code. But it is throwing error as

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

although file is present at the location

```
f=open(r"C:\test_file\myfile.txt","r")
file_content=f.read()
print(file_content)
f.close()
```

any leads would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have permission to read directly under C:\ ? What happens if you open a terminal and do `type C:\test_file\myfile.txt`?

Comment: @Torxed I guess I have..Could you elaborate how to check that?

Comment: Hi. I just did : ) `type` in windows is a way to "print" the file to the console, if that works with a normal user-command prompt, then there's not a permission error. If that's not the problem, I'mt not sure what is. The code is correct. And if the file is in that path that you've supplied as you say it is. This is just straight up weird. Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: @Torxed. Thanks. It was not a permission issue though but it is resolved. Code is looking for myfile.txt and in my windows extensions are hidden so the file became myfile.txt.txt and this was the reason it was failing. But thanks to you i got an idea from the command prompt only.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to reputation score, but have you tried using `\\` instead `\`?

```
f=open("C:\\test_file\\myfile.txt")
file_content=f.read()
print(file_content)
f.close()
```

This code works for me without any problem, though, I don't know your platform.

Comment: Yes I had tried that as well but didn't work. I am using anaconda Spyder (python 3.6) in windows

Comment: The use of `r` in front of a string, means Python won't parse it for anything, including escape characters such as `\ `